# C++ Rate Controller

Tags: c++

This is from a high performance server that needs to block anyone who is doing more than `limit` requests per `seconds` seconds.

You call `check` and if it returns true you process the request, otherwise you block it.

It maintains a circular queue, initialized to 0, of the last times the event was triggered.

I use `time()` because it is faster, in my tests, (on ubuntu) than any other clock measuring function I know of (including all of the C++ timing mechanisms), and 1 second resolution is good enough.

It will be wrong for a few seconds after the 1970 epoch, but I'm not terribly worried about that.

```
class RateController {
    int n, seconds;
    time_t* q;
    int i;
    void push(time_t t) {
        q[i] = t;
        i = (i + 1) % n;
    }
public:
    RateController(int limit, int seconds): n(limit), seconds(seconds) {
        q = new time_t[n];
        memset(q, 0, sizeof(time_t) * n);
        i = 0;
    }
    ~RateController() {
        delete[] q;
    }   
    bool check() {
        time_t t = time(0);
        push(t);
        return (t - q[i]) >= seconds;
    }
};
```

Comment: This is not really c++. Basically C with a class to tie the functions together. In C++ you would/should use  a `std::array` (if size known at compile time) or a `std::vector` with `reserve`.   Maybe a FIFO queue is in fact what you need? ie `std::queue`

Your code is probably faster, because it's basically "raw C". But it would be "safer and easier" with C++'s abstractions.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock There is no explicit requirement to not use the C equivalents when the C++ alternative provides no tangible advantage

Comment: @OliverSchönrock Everything that compiles by a C++ compiler and does not compile with a C compiler is "real C++" IMO. We should not be dogmatic and force a specific style.

Comment: I didn't mean to be dogmatic. And yes of course it's valid. I was simply making the point that if I had used C++ to write that I might have started by using a `std::queue` and seeing if it's "fast enough". If it is, leave it. If I had used C, I might have written something very similar to the above. My comment was merely meant to thought provoking, not critical.

Comment: similarly use of `unique_ptr[]` instead of `new`

Comment: You seem concerned about performance (use of time_t and raw arrays). Yet if your time resolution is only 1sec, and say n = 1000 and s =1. Then if you get >1000 requests per second, then the whole circular queue will fill with the same time. Then block, then when `time()` returns the next second, then the floodgates will open for another 1000 requests. Is this what you want? If it's a lot less then 1000req/s then why are worried about performance? Surely the overhead of any time call would be insignificant?

Comment: Also consider this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2204380/1087626 instead of `memset`

Comment: If I get 1000 requests in 1 millisecond, that is OK, and then 1000 requests in 1 millisecond, the next second, that is OK.  In practice, the "limit" values are typically closer to 20, and the "seconds" values are larger than 1.  I see your point regarding unnecessary optimization, but then why use a complicated setup when something smaller and simpler is available that works?

Comment: and finally: unique_ptr[] and value (ie zero) initalisation together in one statement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21377382/1087626

`std::make_unique<time_t[]>(n);`  which also removes the need for the destructor/delete.

Comment: The reason to use C++ concepts is that they are less error prone and should not introduce any significant (or any) overhead. Using `std::vector` or `std::array` above introduces no overhead but automatically fixes several bugs that your code already has (such not obeying the rule of five).

Comment: How does the rate controller know which user they are checking. Or do you create one per user?

Comment: Yes, each user has its own rate controller object

Comment: @CaptainCodeman One may not be obliged to use C++ tools rather than C ones, but one must admit the C-ish nature of this code.  Were I to see this code at work, I would *instantly* assume that it was written by a C developer who had to use C++ to fit into a larger system.  I would then look for classic C pitfalls because I knew that C++ didn't have my back like it usually does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per my comments under your question, I would suggest that you use some C++ abstractions to do the "heavy" lifting for you. eg don't do your own memory allocation with `new` nor your own initialisation with `memset`.

Consider using a standard container. If in doubt use `std:vector`. You could also use `std::make_unique` to initialise an array, but why? Either way you now don't need a destructor. That's a bigger gain than it seems, because without the destructor, you can comply with the "Rule of zero". With the destructor (ie doing your own resource mgmt) you really need to comply with the "Rule of five", and your current code does not, causing potentially serious bugs as @henje nicely demonstrates below.

Use `std::chrono`: it's really powerful, makes for easy to read code and allows you to easily adjust the resolution of your `RateController`. The overhead is unlikely to be an issue unless you are talking millions of requests per seconds per `RateController`.

While testing I found that your code has a bug: in `check()` you need to test if the comparison is true before calling `push()`, or you constantly overwrite your circular buffer and block the system.

For style designate your member variables by postfixing them with `_` or similar so they are easy to identify. I like to put the public interface first in a class, but it's getting heavily subjective now.

Suggested use of C++ abstractions:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

class RateController {
  using clk_t = std::chrono::system_clock;
  using time_point_t = std::chrono::time_point<clk_t>;

public:
  RateController(unsigned limit, unsigned long milliseconds)
      : n_(limit), milliseconds_(milliseconds),
        q(n_, time_point_t()) {}

  bool check() {
    time_point_t t = clk_t::now();
    bool allowed = t - q[i_] >= std::chrono::milliseconds(milliseconds_);
    if (allowed) push(t);
    return allowed;
  }

private:
  unsigned  n_;
  unsigned long milliseconds_;
  unsigned  i_ = 0;

  std::vector<time_point_t> q;

  void push(time_point_t t) {
    q[i_] = t;
    i_    = (i_ + 1) % n_;
  }
};
```

Algorithmically, your circular buffer idea could certainly work well, but it's quite a lot of storage, if you have many requests per interval. It depends on your use case.

If you have many throusands of clients and therefore many `RateController` instances then perhaps you don't want to store 1000 x 8byte `unsigned long`s (8k) for each one? In that case you could just divide time into predetermined slots (say every 10 minutes) and for each client just keep the time of last request and the number of requests in the current time slice. That would be ~500x less storage? This is similar to what @JerryCoffin was suggesting.

Below is a version which uses the `time_slice` idea. It basically revolves around an integer division. No more `vector` or other circular buffer. The behaviour is not identical, but I prefer this one.

If you are concerned that thousands of these RateController instances  will all unblock at the same time when the new time slice starts and hence cause a load spike, you can address that too. Just generate a random offset in the range [0, time_slice_seconds) during construction and add it to the current time before doing the integer division. If you do this, I can no longer see the advantage of the circular buffer.

```cpp
#include <chrono>

class RateController {
  using clk_t        = std::chrono::system_clock;

public:
  RateController(unsigned limit, long time_slice_seconds)
      : n_(limit), time_slice_(time_slice_seconds) {}

  bool check() {
    auto duration_since_epoch = clk_t::now().time_since_epoch();
    long curr_time_slice =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(duration_since_epoch).count() /
        time_slice_; // integer division!

    if (curr_time_slice != last_time_slice_) {
      last_time_slice_ = curr_time_slice;
      count_           = 0;
    }
    ++count_;
    return (count_ <= n_);
  }

private:
  unsigned n_;
  long     time_slice_;
  long     last_time_slice_ = 0;
  unsigned count_           = 0;
  ;
};
```

Comment: I don't recommend those names beginning with `_`, as they are reserved for the implementation in many contexts.

Comment: I think it's fine for member variables if single underscore is followed by a lower case letter, which it always is for me. But I am still looking for the "ultimate convention" on this. Unfortunately there seems to be little consensus on this. What do you use?

Comment: @TobySpeight I changed it to postfix underscore. Is that better?

Comment: In personal projects, I don't do Hungarian-style markers (it's a good incentive to keep things simple).  At work, I inherited a project that uses `m_` prefix, so my new code there is consistent with the existing.  The real danger of course is `_` followed by uppercase, or `__` anywhere in the identifier - implementations can use those for any purpose, including macros.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed analysis and excellent suggestions; I have already incorporated most of them.  I will say, however, that maintaining a queue is necessary to be able to correctly support short bursts which would otherwise overflow a strictly count-based algorithm.  Even nginx uses a queue for rate limiting (it maintains a separate queue per remote IP)

Comment: Curious, in the constructor, is there a reason to write `q(std::vector<time_point_t>(n_, time_point_t()))` instead of `q(n_, time_point_t())` ?

Comment: yes, the behaviour is not the same, the queue may work  better for your use, ...and yes, that's my bad the initalisation list item for `q` can take the constructor arguments directly, I will ammend. It makes little perf differeny (due to move constructor), but certainly cleaner the way you suggest.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Reviewing this answer and the comments I do not understand what you mean by "maintaining a queue is necessary to be able to correctly support short bursts which would otherwise overflow a strictly count-based algorithm". Can you explain? Note that I have added a paragraph above on random offsets for the timeslices.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock For instance, you want to allow a user to make 2 requests / second on average, but when loading a page they will make 20 requests in one second.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman OK, but how does the circular buffer do something here which the time_slice does not? In both cases the page load will be spread over 20s, right?

Comment: @OliverSchönrock There will be slight differences in behavior; for example you want to limit the rate to 15/minute so your time slice is 60 seconds and the limit/slice is 15. You could have 10 requests come in at 0:59 and then 10 more requests come in, 2 seconds later at 0:01, so you will allow 20 requests within 3 seconds and that technically breaks the 15/minute rate -- the queue version would handle this correctly.  (Arguably it perhaps does not matter for most purposes, but if you must absolutely adhere to some exact rate for some reason, the timeslice method can be incorrect)

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Yes correct. However, this is unrealistic on average. Much more likely that (on average across many clients) the ones that are hungry will take up their quota at start of slice. With randomised start you will get a uniform load distribution.

If your goal is to "smooth load peaks" and get a "steady work load" and if you have more than 100 clients, then (assuming you randomise) statistics will ensure that your load is just as smooth as for the circular buffer.

The case for "over those 2 seconds it's too much", seems pedantic because over 2 mins it's correct.

Answer (score 8):

Overall I'm going to side with Oliver's comment that

> This is not really c++ [...] it would be "safer and easier" with C++'s abstractions.

At your scale, you haven't shown any data convincing me that performance will influence choosing "old-style C++" over new, idiomatic C++; and anyway that shouldn't be your first consideration: your first consideration should be for correctness, robustness and testability. All of those have suffered given the use of unmanaged pointers.

My advice - which falls short of recommending specific C++(17|20) constructs since I'm not strong in that area - is to make it right-first, not fast-first. Write this in a style that has safe memory management practices and has solid unit test coverage, then profile it. If the performance is good enough (and I would be surprised if it isn't, but I've been wrong before) then leave it. If the performance suffers *and* it's the fault of your use of idiomatic C++ *and* reverting to unsafe memory management solves the problem, then fine - revert the slow pieces.

Put another way, you're either going to pay the cost of using newer C++ abstractions to play with memory safely, or you're going to pay in engineering time poring over Valgrind dumps.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions.  I have switched to vector.  I am curious, though, you mentioned "unchecked allocation"; does C++ throw an exception if vector allocation fails?

Comment: You should expect the same `std::bad_alloc` as from `new` if vector allocation fails, so no need to change the exception handling in the calling code.  I'm not sure what this review is referring to by "unchecked allocation", either.

Comment: @TobySpeight Poor wording; I've dropped that phrase.

Answer (score 5):

`time()` and `std::chrono::system_clock` use system time, which can change.  This can cause small issues if, say, NTP changes your clock.  But you'll also find that everything dies once a year in the fall when daylight saving time sends you an hour into the past.  (At least if your system uses local time zones.)

`std::chrono::steady_clock` should avoid such issues and is likely a better choice for timing things instead of getting the actual "human" time.

Comment: This is more a comment on another answer. However, I notice that your reputation doesn't allow you to comment and it's a helpful comment, so you are forgiven in this case :) Welcome to this site!

Comment: That was kind of my thought process too @Sjoerd 

Comment: What you're alluding to is the use of a "monotonic" clock, called different things depending on what OS you're calling into.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I'd at least consider doing this a bit differently. Since multiple requests per second is entirely possible, I'd at least consider keeping a count of the number of requests in a given second:

```cpp
struct count { 
    std::time_t t;
    std::size_t count;
};
```

With this, I'd probably also keep a running count of the number of requests in the last N seconds. Anytime you get a `time_t` different from the most recent on record, you add a new `count` record to your list, and check whether you have any old records to remove from the list. If so, subtract the count for each of them from your current count as you remove them.

But a bit here depends on how fast you really expect to receive requests. If you could have multiple incoming requests per second, this is likely to be a useful optimization. If you're expecting more on the order of multiple seconds between requests, it may be a waste of time.

Assuming we ignore that and stick to some variant of the current design, I'd start by observing that your class really has two rather separate responsibilities. One is keep track of time and timeouts and figuring out whether a request is allowed or not. The other is maintaining a circular buffer you use to implement that.

I'd try to decouple those, such as using a relatively generic circular buffer, and then a class to enforce the timeout that's implemented using the circular buffer.

Comment: The problem with this is that you may have to clear N records in one go, if some time has passed since the last request.  (Unless I misunderstood?)

Answer (score 3):

"This RateController seems handy, I can use it in my function, great!"

```cpp
bool use_controller(RateController rate_ctr) {
    return rate_ctr.check();
}

int main() {
    RateController rate_ctr{10, 1};
    bool check = use_controller(rate_ctr);
    return rate_ctr.check() || check;
}
```

"Let me just run it in my debug build, and ..., woah"

```
=================================================================
==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x607000000028 at pc 0x0000004fa54f bp 0x7fffce7fed80 sp 0x7fffce7fed78
READ of size 8 at 0x607000000028 thread T0
...
0x607000000028 is located 8 bytes inside of 80-byte region [0x607000000020,0x607000000070)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x4f7710  (/app/output.s+0x4f7710)
    #1 0x4fa508  (/app/output.s+0x4fa508)

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x4f6d48  (/app/output.s+0x4f6d48)
    #1 0x4fa4e0  (/app/output.s+0x4fa4e0)
```

On a more serious note, you have a bug in your code. This scenario might seem a little contrived but, in general, libraries should be easy to use and hard to misuse. One can easily misuse the controller like in my example code.

The class you are implementing handles a resource and has to implement a copy-constructor and operator= to deal with copies gracefully. Alternatively, you could delete these functions to at least raise a compiler error, when the class is misused.

This could have been prevented by using a more idiomatic C++ solution, like other answers have provided. Implementing a resource-handling class is not trivial and in most cases not necessary because library classes exist to handle most cases.

One way to avoid this bug is to use `std::unique_ptr` which is not copyable and would make your class non-copyable as well. When you use a `std::vector` like in Oliver Schönrock's answer, the vector handles copying and allocates a new buffer for you. Then again you might want to be able to copy a controller but refer to the same queue. In this case you could use a `std::shared_ptr`.

You might want to look into the rule of zero/three/five as it helps with gotchas of custom types. In general, the best way is to use library types which remove the need for you to implement special functions at all.

You can try my test code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/rbojEj). I recommend to use tools like AddressSanitizer (UBSAN, TSAN, vagrant) for catching subtle bugs.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, you are correct, the original code doesn't handle copying correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This looks more like C code than C++.  I echo the other reviewers: use the abstractions that are available to you (and understand how they work, to have a grasp on the performance characteristics).

However, if you *are* using C functions in your C++ code, prefer to use the native C++ headers `<ctime>` and `<cstring>` rather than `<time.h>` and `<string.h>`.  Then you get neatly namespaced versions of the identifiers you use:

- `std::time_t`
- `std::time()`
- `std::memset()`

Comment: <ctime> is allowed to dump the same identifiers in the global namespace as well, and most implementations do.So your advice doesn't help. Actually, a better advice is to use a C++ container and the C++ <chrono> header, as other answers say.

Comment: It is indeed *allowed* to to so.  But it's foolish (needlessly non-portable) to assume all targets will do that.  Yes, using `<chrono>` is obviously better for the time stuff (and perhaps `std::fill()` rather than `std::memset()`), but this advice applies to all of the C standard library.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add to Oliver Schönrock's answer, and specifically address the comment you made:

> I will say, however, that maintaining a queue is necessary to be able to correctly support short bursts which would otherwise overflow a strictly count-based algorithm.

You can support bursts without maintaining a queue, by implementing a [leaky bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket):

```
#include <chrono>

class RateController {
  using clock_t      = std::chrono::steady_clock;
  using time_point_t = clock_t::time_point;
  using duration_t   = clock_t::duration;

public:
  RateController(unsigned limit, duration_t interval)
      : limit_(limit), interval_(interval) {}

  bool check() {
    // Try to drain the bucket
    if (count_) {
        auto now = clock_t::now();
        auto time_passed = now - last_update_;
        auto drained = time_passed / interval_;

        if (drained) {
            count_ -= drained < count_ ? drained : count_;
            last_update_ = now;
        }
    }

    if (count_ < limit_) {
        ++count_;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }

private:
  const unsigned limit_;
  const duration_t interval_;
  time_point_t last_update_ = clock_t::now();
  unsigned count_           = 0;
};
```

Comment: Good catch, yes you are right.

Comment: Wouldn't updating `last_update_` like that would result in incorrect rate throughput overall? Seems like it would be better to keep track when first "drop" was added to the bucket and when `check(...)` is called all you need to compare if bucket is empty (reset `count`), or if bucket is full (taking into account duration since when first drop was added.

Comment: @PavelP You're correct... it should do something like `last_update_ += drained * interval_` if `drained < count_`, and maybe some other tweaks. Basically, you want the changes in `count_` and `last_update_` to be in sync.